# iReport/JasperReports Server: Subreport return value null

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver, subreport

I have the following problem with *iReport / JasperReports server*.

I'm using a main reports with two subreports returning a calculated price, the type of the subreport variable and the local variable is **BigDecimal**.

If the return value from a subreport is null (no rows found) then the assigned local variable in the main report is always null. But I want to have "0.00" because I want to calculate a sum.

The construct `(return_variable == null ? new BigDecimal(0) : return_variable)` doesn't help as well as to set the local variable to a default value `new BigDecimal(0)`. I always get ***null*** instead of the wanted value ***"0.00"*** ;-(

I've tested with version 3.7.6 until 4.4. of *iReport*, nothing helps.

Does anybody have a hint for me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the variable value in a band of the subreport? Does it still say null? What happens when you run the subreport alone? What type of database are you using?

Comment: Hi Lisa, thanks for the response. inside the band of subreport (group footer) the variable is **0** (not null) after this band the same variable is **null**, I've running a postgres 9.0 database. If I call up the subreport with the options then I get nothing back because the number of results is null. Thats why I want to replace the null (no values) to 0.00€

Comment: Is it possible that the construct you gave above is not actually setting the null value to 0 permanently? I take it that the value in your subreport is also a sum (because it's in your group footer). For your database, is there a way to take a null value in each row of the dtail band and make it zero? In Oracle, I would use the COALESCE or DECODE functions and then sum up the results. Then the group footer value would be 0 even if the individual values were all nulls.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time, it didn't help ;-( I've started with a new report an try to do it in that way. Maybe is a problem with different versions of ireport I'm using, no idea. There are some problems I've realized with newer versions of ireport, e.g. a BigDecimal field was changed to String automatically. Will see if it helps when I start a new repoprt. Thank you again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returned value from subeport to main report is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384421/returned-value-from-subeport-to-main-report-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, except I tried to use the return value of the subreport as a parameter of another subreport. I succeeded in getting the result I wanted by using a scriptlet in the second subreport.

I proceeded this way :
-in subreport 2, I have my parameter p (Float), its value being the return value of subreport 1
-in subreport 2, I have a variable v (Float), initialized with p
-in my scriptlet (in the method beforeDetailEval(), I test my variable v : if it is null, I assign the value new Float("0.0")

I works ok.

The limitation with this is if you want to use the return value of your subreport directly in your main report. I tried doing that, but never succeeded.

Hope this will help someone some day.

Cecilka

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! By the Grace of GOD, I found a great answer to my own question. Posting it as it may help someone in future.

```
1) I changed my Simple SQL Query with a MySQL stored procedure as.
```

My Stored Procedure as

```
BEGIN
SET @p = 0;
SET @n = 0;
SET @m = '00';
SELECT x.*, y.* FROM 
     (select @n:=@n+1 as "ID", @m:=acc as "Account" from tbl_reports) x
        right JOIN 
     (SELECT if(@m='00',0,@p:=@p+1) as "IDU") y
ON y.IDU = x.ID;
END
```

In IReport, I declared my variable as

```
$F{IDU}>0?$F{Amount}:0
```

In this way, it now shows 0.00 instead of null.